# How can I make a button exactly the same size of its text?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Is it possible to make a `JButton` take exactly the size of its text? Since by default, a `JButton` will have a small amount of padding (both horizontal and vertical) around its text. I would like to remove that padding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`JButton` has a border by default, you can remove it:

```
button.setBorder(null);
```

---

If you want to keep the border, reduce the margin (see [Eugenes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2713814/17343))

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for asking such a simple question.

Comment: thank you, was going nuts trying to find where the damn padding was being set.

Comment: -1 This answer removes the border.  That's not what OP asked for.  See the other answer to clear the margins without removing the border.

Comment: It is interesting that setting `btn.setBorderPainted(false)` does not do the same. You'd think it would.

Answer (score 12):

**Clear out the margins in the button with [`setMargin`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin(java.awt.Insets)).**

Removing the border has the side-effect of removing the border.  If you only want to clear out the margins, use the [`setMargin`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin(java.awt.Insets)) method to set the margins all to zero.

```
button.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
```

Comment: On my system I measured 16 pixels of horizontal padding left and right of the text before using this approach and 15 pixels after. There seems to be something else adding padding other than the button. Maybe the label the button creates for itself? I think the solution depends on the L&F and the system. I'm on macOS Big Sur using the default L&F and JDK 11.