# Java JButton Size

Tags: java, jbutton

I know there are some other questions similar to this but I haven't seen my specific question answered. I want to change the size of a JButton WITHOUT changing the look. For example if I use setPreferredSize, I lose the white background color and rounded corners. I just want to remove the surrounding padding so the button is only slightly bigger then it's label.

```
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Label");
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    JButton jButtonUp = new JButton("Upd");
    //jButtonUp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
    jPanel.add(jButtonUp, gbc);

    gbc.gridy = 1;
    JButton jButtonDn = new JButton("Del");
    //jButtonDn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
    jPanel.add(jButtonDn, gbc);

    jFrame.add(jPanel);
    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Using Mac OSX Sierra.

What I have is this: [image]

What I get with setPreferredSize is this: [image]

What I want is this: [image]

Comment: updated with code

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  Can you show complete code?  And make two buttons please so it's easier to compare them.  What Look and Feel do you use and what OS and version are you on?

Comment: Both of these buttons have the same look for me on Windows 10 and Java 8.  I'm on the latest update for both.  Sorry but it seems it might be Mac specific. (BTW, both buttons are the same size and tiny on my screen.  There's a reason why we normally don't set the size of GUI components directly and it's because screen sizes, pixel density and default font sizes differ on each machine.  Might be best to not set the size at all.)

Comment: You updated your code to a full example, but the created button is neither white, nor has round edges when I copy the code in a main method.

Comment: Yes. That's the problem of setPreferredSize. Comment it out.

Comment: Did that, still blue with edgy edges.

Comment: Must be mac look and feel is different.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2712665/7347939), Simply do

After the line:

```
JButton jButtonUp = new JButton("Upd");
```

Add:

```
jButtonUp.setBorder(null);
jButtonUp.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
```

Then add the button to the panel:

```
jPanel.add(jButtonUp, gbc);
```

Comment: Thanks but no good. That just gets rid of the border of the button and displays only text. Also, jButtonDn.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0)) does nothing.

Comment: you can check the reference, which is setting the margin. It should work for ur case.

Comment: Not sure what "the reference" means.

Comment: @JohnSmith, below is the link answer for the reference.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2713814/7347939

Comment: No that doesn't work. setMargin doesn't work as I said earlier.